# Subclassing from Dict violates basic rule of object oriented programming in python

Tags: python, oop

I am requesting better insights on the author's comments for a particular section of code. To go much in detail, I will illustrate with an example.

```
 class DoppelDict(dict):           
     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, [value] * 2)

 # case 1.
 dd = DoppelDict(one=1)
 print(dd)  # {'one':1}

 # case 2.
 dd['two'] = 2
 print(dd)  # {'one':1,'two':[2,2]}
```

The above example is picked from a book and the author comments 'Built-in behavior is a violation of a basic rule of object-oriented programming: the search for methods should always start from the class of the target instance (self), even when the call happens inside a method implemented in a superclass'.

I believe the author is trying to convey since python ignores special methods overridden by user-defined class, it is a violation of OOP. I wanted to know whether my explanation is correct?. Do you have any other explanation to author comments?.

Comment: No. You are responsible - if you change the behaviour of `__setitem__` you also have to override your  `__init__`. If not your arguments are just passed onto the super()class and how should that be able to "see" your changed implementation?

Comment: @Anakhand that's not true, when you do `DoppelDict(one=1)` the `__init__` of super class is being called since it has not been overridden and when you actually do `dd['two']`, the `__setitem__` is being called which is found in the class of instance itself. Its all related to `MRO`.

Comment: Yes, is like say PatrickArtner and Rohit. Despite of you are orverriden __setitem__ you need to override __init__ method too. I have curiosity, what  book are you reading?

Comment: Thanks @s326280

Comment: I suppose that the book's author expected that the `dict`'s `__init__` method would make use of `__setitem__` when creating the dict. It doesn't. Looking at the source code, (if I looked at the right function...), it is done using an `update`.

Comment: The "basic rule" is "Don't guess! The source code is always right, when in doubt, read the source code.".

Answer (score 5):

I can't really comment on the "*Built-in behavior is a violation of a basic rule of object-oriented programming:*". But in your code there are two separate and very different things happening.

When you do

```
dd = DoppelDict(one=1)
```

This looks for `__init__` in the `MRO` and since your class didn't override `__init__` and so `__init__` method of the `super` class which is `dict` is called.

However when you do

```
dd['two'] = 2
```

python looks for `__setitem__` method in the `MRO` which you have overriden and hence it is called and you get the expected result.

Its all related to `super` and `MRO`. You can easily look at the `MRO` for any class by simply checking `__mro__` attribute.

```
In[5]: a = 100
In[6]: a.__class__.__mro__
Out[6]: (int, object)
```

The above example is just for an builtin class but the same applies to any other custom class as well.

Comment: I  understood that this thread is more about whether the behaviour you described is correct in terms of OOP principles.

Comment: I don't think this is general OOP behavior rather this is very specific to python.

Comment: @Rohit, if you override the init method, can you achieve the behaviour similar to the case #2

Comment: @s326280 ofcourse, i just highlighted that what was happening there in the background, obviously for something like dicts you need to override both the methods.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is an implemetation detail problem - it highly depends on what the super-called contructor of the base class does - in this case it does *not* call `__setitem__`.

You can fix it though:

```
class DoppelDict(dict):
    # force it to use setitem instead of update
    def __init__(self, *kargs, **kwargs):
        # probably also should do something with kargs
        for k,w in kwargs.items():
            super().__setitem__(k,[w]*2)  # see Graipher comment - for less code duplication
                                          # one could use self[k] = w .. plus 1 function call
                                          # but less code duplication for the special logic
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, [value] * 2)

# case 1.
dd = DoppelDict(one=1)
print(dd)  # {'one': [1, 1]}

# case 2.
dd['two'] = 2
print(dd)  # {'one': [1, 1], 'two': [2, 2]}
```

In pythons dict-case it does not use `__setitem__`.

---

You can have the same problem in "fully" OOP languages, for example in C#:

```csharp
public class Base
{
    public Base(Dictionary<string, int> d)
    {
        // if the base constructor internally uses SetItem(..) it works as expected
        // if you overload SetItem in the Child-Klasses:
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)
            SetItem(kvp); 

        // if the base constructor does _not_ use SetItem(..) it does not work by
        // overloading child classes SetItem() method: 
        // foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d) 
        //    D[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value; 
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> D { get; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public override string ToString() 
        => string.Join(",", D.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}"));

    protected virtual void SetItem(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp) => D[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
}

public class Other : Base
{
    public Other(Dictionary<string, int> d) : base(d) { }

    // overridden implementation doubling the incoming value
    protected override void SetItem(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp)
        => D[kvp.Key] = 2 * kvp.Value;
}
```

You can test this using

```csharp
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int> { ["a"] = 1, ["b"] = 3 };

    Base b = new Base(d);
    Other o = new Other(d);

    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and commenting either one of the `Base()`-ctor implementations.

You either get (not using `SetItem(..)`)

```
a=1,b=3
a=1,b=3
```

or (using `SetItem(..)`)

```
a=1,b=3
a=1,b=6
```

as outputs.

Comment: In the fixed `DoppelDictionary` chouldn't it just be `self[k] = w` instead of `super().__setitem__(k,[w]*2)`? Since that does use `__setitem__`.

Comment: @Graipher that depends on what other things are done in my overridden `__setItem__` - the result for this code is the same, by using the direct call to super inside the ctor I need to do any changes in 2 places (code duplication:bad) but I get one less stackframe switch from not calling another function (maybe good if you construct millions of things) ... generally I would lean towards your suggestion for less maintenance - the needed logic here is simple and it will work both ways.

Comment: @Graipher edited your suggestion in as code comment in case the comment below vanishes

Comment: Not sure if you really get one less stack frame switch/code call. `super` also needs to be called in your version...